# Ogr2ogr trying to import and convert shapefile to EPSG:3857

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, epsg

I'm attempting to import a shapefile (along with .prj file) to MySQL using Ogr2ogr and using the t_srs option set to EPSG:3857 (the default for Leaflet and Google Maps) but I'm getting odd results, eg:

```
POLYGON((-11368056.30134075 7311108.362629404,-11373244.15325952 7311276.412255973,-11372957.24394724 7313966.399114295,-11367933.92414896 7312806.137997068,-11368056.30134075 7311108.362629404)),1
```

the command I'm using is:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:db,host=host,user=user,password=pass sourceDir -nln destTable -t_srs EPSG:3857 -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

the .prj in the sourceDir is

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-105.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Any suggestions as to the problem?

Comment: I would try to find an EPSG code for the source SRS and give it as -s_srs and see if it has some effect.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference I'm afraid, it's the first thing I tried but shouldn't be necessary anyway with the .prj file. It's EPSG:26913.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered my error. I was expecting to see lat/lng pairs from EPSG:3857, but it's actually EPSG:4326 I should have been converting to.